# How can I write a script to remove whole rows if a cell in a column matches a value in another in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, row, cell, matching

Been very frustrating to figure this out. Lets say I have 5 columns in google sheets and there's 10,000 data points in column B, while column E only has 500 and each column has random strings of numbers (i.e. b2=46, b3=75, e2=177, e3=1, and so on). I want to iterate a loop that goes through column e, and if at any point a cell value matches that in column B it deletes the whole row in column B. I'm very stumped unfortunately, could someone help me out with this?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It is unclear what you mean by "the whole row in column B". Do you mean from column `A` to column `D`, from `A` to `E`, from `A` to `Z`, or just `B`?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is probably to get all the values, use `Array.filter()` to leave just the rows that do *not* match any of the keys in `E2:E`, and finally use `Range.setValues()` to write the remaining rows back to the spreadsheet, like this:

```
/**
* Deletes rows in A2:D where the value in column B equals
* at least one value in E2:E.
*/
function deleteMatchingRows() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const keysToDelete = sheet.getRange('E2:E').getValues().flat();
  const range = sheet.getRange('A2:D');
  const searchColumn = 1; // zero-indexed; column A = 0, B = 1...
  const values = range.getValues();
  const filtered = values.filter(row => !keysToDelete.includes(row[searchColumn]));
  range.clearContent();
  range.offset(0, 0, filtered.length, filtered[0].length).setValues(filtered);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function delRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  let d = 0;
  const bvs = sh.getRange(1, 2, sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  sh.getRange(1, 5, sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().filter(e => e).forEach(e => {
    let idx = bvs.indexOf(e);
    if(~idx) {
      sh.deleteRow(idx + 1 - d++);
    }
  })
}
```